# How can I navigate my CSS to update the webkit animation duration with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, css-animations

I want to update the duration of .s-animate where it says:

```
.circle-half:nth-of-type(1):after {
  -webkit-animation: rotateLeftMask $duration infinite linear;
}
.circle-half:nth-of-type(2):after {
  -webkit-animation: rotateRightMask $duration infinite linear;
}
```

I'm guessing I don't need to have the duration defined to begin with. But even without it defined I can't seem to select the right element and I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '-webkit-animation-duration' of undefined

CSS:

```
/* animate circle */

.circle {
// CONFIG
$size: 300px;
$thickness: 6px;
$duration: 10s;

overflow: hidden;
height: $size;
width: $size;
position: relative;
background: red;


.circle-half {
height: $size;
width: $size/2;
border-radius: $size/2 0 0 $size/2;
background: $blue;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;

&:nth-of-type(2) {
  z-index: 99999999;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);

}

&:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: $thickness;
  left: $thickness;
  height: $size - 2*$thickness;
  width: ($size - 2*$thickness)/2;
  border-radius: ($size - $thickness)/2 0 0 ($size - $thickness)/2;
  background: $white;
}
&:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: $white;
  height: $size*2;
  width: $size*1.5;
  left: -$size;
  top: -$size/2;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
}
}

&.s-animate {
-webkit-transform-origin: center right;
.circle-half:nth-of-type(1):after {
  -webkit-animation: rotateLeftMask $duration infinite linear;
}
.circle-half:nth-of-type(2):after {
  -webkit-animation: rotateRightMask $duration infinite linear;
}
}
}
```

JS:

```
  // Set duration
    function setLineDuration() {
       var timeString = time.toString() + 's';
       console.log(timeString);
       $('.s-animate').find('.circle-half:nth-of-type(1):after').style['-webkit-animation'] = timeString;
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="circleContainer" class="grid">
  <div class="circle s-animate center">
    <div class="circle-half"></div>
    <div class="circle-half"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get at a "style" object for pseudo-elements like `:before` and `:after`. They're not really in the DOM.

Comment: @Pointy how would I do so if I needed to navigate to a class name?

Comment: That's not really how it works. When you manipulate the style object of an element, you're *adding* CSS rules on the element directly. Those changes have no effect on the CSS rules in your CSS `<style>` blocks or CSS files, but they do override those settings.

Comment: @Pointy ok so then it should still work in this case. Assuming I'm trying just for this class and not the psuedo elements. What what I need to write?

Comment: `$(".s-animate").find(".circle-half").css("property", "value")` - you're using jQuery so you should use the jQuery API to operate on jQuery objects.